# Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian Theorem for stochastic processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, tauberian-theory

For which processes do we have
$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} X_t dt =\lim_{a\to 0}a\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at}X_t dt 
$$
almost surely?

The Hardy Littlewood implies that this holds for processes that are bounded below or above. But I feel like there is a non trivial generalization under suitable autocorrelation assumptions.

Comment: By carefully reading the title, it seems that you want to ensure the equality provided the right-hand side converges. Is this right? I think it is good to clarify the assumption you are imposing so that you are really considering Tauberian theorem.

Comment: @SangchuiLee Anything helps. If you have conditions that ensure both sides exist and are equal almost surely, I'll be happy. If you have conditions that ensure both sides are equal almost surely if one side exists almost surely, I'll be happy. If you have conditions that ensure one side exists if and only if the other exists and they are equal if they exist, I'm happy. Existence in all of this includes plus and minus infinity.